# Excel to Access import, column determines field value

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, excel-2010, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create an Access database to track income and expenditures for a number of accounts.

My difficulty is that my boss insists the people responsible for reporting expenditures on these accounts should only use the existing Excel spreadsheet to do so.  I can import from Excel, but I'm locked into the existing format for the sheet.

In simplified form, the sheet has these columns:

> Account ID  ||  Expense Type A || Expense Type B || Expense Type C  (etc)

I anticipate needing to add new types of expense in the future, so the tables need to accommodate that.

I had thought to structure the Expenses table like so:

> Account_ID || Expense_Type || Expense_Date || Amount

with more info on Type stored in its own table.   But I can't figure out how to map the columns of the spreadsheet to a type classification in the record. There are about 300 accounts with 5 expense types at present, and both may grow.

Can anyone help me with this?  I'll entertain any sort of solution: Excel tricks or changing my database setup or whatever else might work.

PS. I'm a novice with VBA - I've only used it in the sense of recording macros.

Comment: @pnuts Using Excel and Access 2010.  Yes, a row may have multiple entries.  There's no date column yet; at present the spreadsheet is being created anew every month, and someone cut-and-pastes when they want a history for any particular account (one of several reasons I want to move to Access).  We only need the month-year portion, not day, so easy enough to add in old sheets.

Answer (score 1):

After you've imported the spreadsheet into a temporary table in Access you could run the following query to "de-crosstab" the data

```
SELECT [Account ID] AS Account_ID, "Expense Type A" AS Expense_Type, 
        [Expense Type A] AS Amount
    FROM TempTable WHERE [Expense Type A] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [Account ID] AS Account_ID, "Expense Type B" AS Expense_Type, 
        [Expense Type B] AS Amount
    FROM TempTable WHERE [Expense Type B] IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT [Account ID] AS Account_ID, "Expense Type C" AS Expense_Type, 
        [Expense Type C] AS Amount
    FROM TempTable WHERE [Expense Type C] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Call up the 'old' Pivot Table wizard with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`D` and `P`, select Multiple consolidation ranges and PivotTable, Next, select I will create the page fields, Next, enter Range, Next, Finish then double click on Grand Totals intersection.